# Not a correct subscript?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, forcing

In his book Proper and Improper forcing on page $42$ in the proof of Fact 7.3 on line $4$
Shelah says "where ${\cal S_{\leq \aleph_1}}(A)$" but he never uses this expression.
He only uses it with subscript $0$ on the same line: $\leq\aleph_0$ but not $\leq\aleph_1$.
So something is wrong here and not as intended ?

[image]

Comment: Yes, that’s pretty clearly a typo for $\mathcal{S}_{\le\aleph_0}(A)$.